How do I omit fields completely when selecting in GORM?
I have my GORM Schemas shown below. Two tables i.e Items and Users. Every item is has a user who created the item.
type Item struct {
    ID          uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primaryKey"`
    Title       string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Description string         `gorm:"type:varchar(450)"`
    CreatorID   uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid"`
    CreatorUser  User           `gorm:"foreignKey:CreatorID;references:ID"`
    IsDeleted   bool           `gorm:"type:boolean;default:false"`

}

type User struct {
    ID                uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primaryKey"`
    Username          string         `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null"`
    Age               int            `gorm:"type:int"`
    Password          string         `gorm:"type:varchar(100);"`
    Email             string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Bio               string         `gorm:"type:varchar(450)"`
    Role              string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Address           string         `gorm:"type:varchar(100)"`
    State             string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Country           string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50);not null"`
    Balance           float64        `gorm:"type:numeric(13,2);default:100.00"`
    Currency          string         `gorm:"type:varchar(4);default:'INR'"`
    IsDeleted         bool           `gorm:"type:boolean;default:false"`
    
    
}



When I select the fields using the GORM query below
    var item gormSchemas.Item
    err = pr.gormDb.Model(&item).Preload("CreatorUser", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select("id, username, email, bio, country, is_deleted,date_created")
    }).Preload("Organization", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select("id, name, bio, location, website")
    }).First(&item, "id = ?", itemId).Error

I seem to get the following response
{
            "ID": "d4e764e0-f20a-4d45-88a7-c4eff9afbaac",
            "Title": "Bluetooth Portable Speaker",
            "Description": "Compact and powerful Bluetooth portable speaker with excellent sound quality and a long-lasting battery. Perfect for on-the-go music enjoyment.",
                             "IsDeleted": false,
                "CreatorUser": {
                "ID": "b07e0a43-b4e1-4dc5-a317-813a6eaca6b1",
                "Username": "blah",
                "Age": 0,
                "Password": "",
                "Email": "blah@example.com",
                "Bio": "I love coding!",
                "Role": "",
                "Address": "",
                "State": "",
                "Country": "USA",
                "Balance": 0,
                "Currency": "",
                "IsDeleted": false,
                "IsVerified": false,
                "DateCreated": "2024-07-24T09:33:57.829562Z",
                "ProfilePictureUrl": "",
                "Organizations": null,
                "LastLoggedIn": "2024-07-24T09:33:57.829562Z"
            },
}

The problem is that I do not want to fetch fields like password, role, balance, currency from users table when joining. The fields should not appear at all.
I tried omitting the fields using the query below but the field still appears albeit empty
pr.gormDb.Preload("CreatorUser", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Omit("Password", "Role","Balance").Select("id, username, email, bio, country, is_deleted, is_verified, date_created, profile_picture_url, last_logged_in")
    }).


My guess is that the fields are appearing empty because that is the zero value for those types in Go. https://go.dev/tour/basics/12

@AlexMeuer that is correct. I want it to not appear at all

you can create a different struct for this case. for example if he is in the items domain, you can create a new struct for users who don't have a password, role, balance, currency
example :
type Item struct {
    ID          uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primaryKey"`
    Title       string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Description string         `gorm:"type:varchar(450)"`
    CreatorID   uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid"`
    CreatorUser  User           `gorm:"foreignKey:CreatorID;references:ID"`
    IsDeleted   bool           `gorm:"type:boolean;default:false"`

}

type User struct {
    ID                uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primaryKey"`
    Username          string         `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null"`
    Age               int            `gorm:"type:int"`
    Email             string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Bio               string         `gorm:"type:varchar(450)"`
    Address           string         `gorm:"type:varchar(100)"`
    State             string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Country           string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50);not null"`
    IsDeleted         bool           `gorm:"type:boolean;default:false"`    
}

or if you response as json you can add

tag json:"-"

example :
type User struct {
    ID                uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primaryKey"`
    Username          string         `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null"`
    Age               int            `gorm:"type:int"`
    Password          string         `gorm:"type:varchar(100);" json:"-"`
    Email             string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Bio               string         `gorm:"type:varchar(450)"`
    Role              string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)" json:"-"`
    Address           string         `gorm:"type:varchar(100)"`
    State             string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Country           string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50);not null"`
    Balance           float64        `gorm:"type:numeric(13,2);default:100.00" json:"-"`
    Currency          string         `gorm:"type:varchar(4);default:'INR'" json:"-"`
    IsDeleted         bool           `gorm:"type:boolean;default:false"`
}

iam prefer use 2x query for this case like
I prefer to use 2x query for cases like this. for example I create another function for get user
example Singular
GetItemByID(db gorm.Db,id string) (Item, Error) {
}
GetUserIByID(db gorm.Db,id string) (User, Error) {
}

item := GetItemByID(db,id)
user := GetUserIByID(db, item.CreatorID)
item.CreatorUser = user

example Plural
GetItems(db gorm.Db) ([]Item, Error) {
}
GetUserIByIDs(db gorm.Db,id []string) ([]Users, Error) {
// you can use query IN(abd,ads)
// db.In(your user ids)
}

and in usecase/service you can use

mapUserByID

items := GetItems(db)
userIDs := make(string, 0)
for _, v := range items {
   userIDs = append(userIDs, v.CreatorID)
} 

users := GetUserIByIDs(db, ids) ([]Users, Error)

mapUser := make(map[string]User)
for _, v := range users {
   mapUser[v.ID] = v
}

for i, v := range items {
   items[i].CreatorUser = mapUser[v.CreatorID]
}

thankyou

Does json:"-" affect the query when inserting data? Or when creating data?

What if I want to fetch fields that have json:"-" annotated with it in other queries?

you can add omitempty on tag json, like this. type Person struct { Name string json:"name" Age int json:"age,omitempty" Email string json:"email,omitempty" }
It is added to the field tag to indicate that the field should be omitted from the JSON output if its value is the zero value of the type.
The zero value depends on the type of the field, but for most types, it is either nil, false, 0, or an empty string.

Oh got it yes thank you. A bit cumbersome but okay

Okay, if you have any confusion, just ask.
